# Migration from Squarespace to Magento Addressing 301 Redirects on Mass

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, 301-redirect

Long story short, we want to add only .html at the end of every category for the purpose of 301 redirects.

So an old category in Squarespace is like below:

www.domainname.com/categoryname

And in Magento2 we need it to be the below:

www.domainname.com/categoryname.html

Yes, I could add them in 1 by 1 through normal Magento 2 fashion. Looking for a concept to do on mass though? So essentially just adding .html to the end of the URL redirect for categories only. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can try: **STORES > Configuration > CATALOG > Catalog > Search Engine Optimization > Category URL Suffix**

[image]

Comment: That won't redirect the old URL to the new though, it will give 404 on the old Squarespace URL strings that are clicked through indexed in Google. The URL rewrite's will need to be listed somewhere. I.e. to redirect /oldcategory to /oldcategory.html